# Hibernate detached criteria sum

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

This is my first post ever, I usually find the answers im looking for here, but this time i'm stumped.

Below are two sql queries - by first getting the values and then doing a "sum" on the results almost halves the duration, but replicating this with Hibernate Criteria is not that straight forward.

From related posts ive found it looks like the answer will more than likely be some DetachedCriteria function, but I cant find any examples where its been used with "sum".

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT(account))) FROM history;
duration 6363ms

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT account);
duration 3624ms
```

My Hibernate criteria for the first query:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.countDistinct("account"));

    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(History.class)
        .setProjection(proj);

    System.out.println(crit.list());
```